# How to change the classpath and run the code in Java?

Tags: java

I was trying to execute the following code in java:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

import org.fife.ui.rtextarea.*;
import org.fife.ui.rsyntaxtextarea.*;

public class TextEditorDemo extends JFrame {

   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


   public TextEditorDemo() {

      JPanel cp = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

      RSyntaxTextArea textArea = new RSyntaxTextArea();
      textArea.setSyntaxEditingStyle(SyntaxConstants.SYNTAX_STYLE_JAVA);
      RTextScrollPane sp = new RTextScrollPane(textArea);
      cp.add(sp);

      setContentPane(cp);
      setTitle("RSyntaxTextArea 1.4 - Example 1 - Text Editor Demo");
      setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      pack();
      setLocationRelativeTo(null);

   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      // Start all Swing applications on the EDT.
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            new TextEditorDemo().setVisible(true);
         }
      });
   }

}
```

Since I'm using [RSyntaxTextArea](http://fifesoft.com/rsyntaxtextarea/) file i have to give the classpath of it while I'm running the code. 
Assume that my RSyntaxTextArea.jar file is in Anto(i.e. my Home directory in Ubuntu 10.10) and when I run the above code:

```
javac -classpath \Anto\RSyntaxTextArea.jar TextEditorDemo.java
```

Still I'm getting the error as `RTextScrollPane` could not be found kind of errors. I guess i have been giving my classpath wrongly; What to do?

Thanks for the answer.

Comment: souldn't it be `javac -classpath /home/Anto/RSyntaxTextArea.jar TextEditorDemo.java`. In Ubuntu, the path separator is "/"

Comment: ya i made this as mistake, i'm novice to ubuntu too:) thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that /Anto is really your home directory, try this:

```
javac -classpath ~/RSyntaxTextArea.jar TextEditorDemo.java
```

Otherwise, just point to a relative path to the jar file.  For one thing, you were trying to use \, where in Linux you should be using /.  You can reference the current directory with .  So, if the jar is in your current working directory, you can just do this:

```
javac -classpath RSyntaxTextArea.jar TextEditorDemo.java
```

Or this:

```
javac -classpath ./RSyntaxTextArea.jar TextEditorDemo.java
```

If the Anto directory is under the current directory, use this:

```
javac -classpath ./Anto/RSyntaxTextArea.jar TextEditorDemo.java
```

Comment: if i run like this i'm getting an another error stating that: `Class names, 'TextEditorDemo', are only accepted if annotation processing is explicitly requested`

Comment: @groovyuser Sorry, I left out the .java suffix.  Copy/paste error.  I fixed it.

Comment: Ya i have included that, even though i'm getting the same error as before, that `RSyntaxTextArea` could not be found. By the way RSyntaxTextArea is a zip file! I'm very much confused!

Comment: That would be your problem.  If that zip file has the proper JAR structure, with a manifest.mf file and the .class at the root, then just rename it to .jar instead of .zip.  Otherwise, you may just need to extract the zip file to your local folder.  You should see RSyntaxTextArea.class in your local folder, then you don't even need to supply a .classpath parameter at all.

Comment: @GroovyUser - *zip* - that explains it all. Most likely the *jar* it inside the zip. Extract is and only add the jar to the classpath.

Comment: @Andreas: now i have made it as .jar file, now even if i run by using the following command : `javac -classpath rsyntaxtextarea.jar TextEditorDemo.java` i'm still facing the same problem..

Comment: @groovyuser Can you tell us what is in that zip file by decompressing it?  Rename it back to .zip and run "unzip file.zip" or "gunzip file.zip".  It should extract it to the current directory?  Do you see a resultant .jar or .class file?

Comment: @squawknull: when i unzip it i'm getting the folder namely **distfiles,i18n,src,build.xml**

Comment: @groovyuser what is under distfiles?

Comment: Download the version at: http://sourceforge.net/projects/rsyntaxtextarea/files/rsyntaxtextarea/1.5.1/rsyntaxtextarea_1.5.1.zip/download, extract it, there will be a jar there, add that to the classpath using one of the methods above to point to it.

Comment: that is perfect! now its getting compiled, now when i run by using the following `java -classpath rsyntaxtextarea.jar;. TextEditorDemo`. I'm not getting the output :(

Comment: Can you please help me with how to run?

Comment: Sorry, help you run what?  If it's regarding the lack of output, that would probably be best as a separate question.  Or, do you mena something else?

Answer (score 2):

Did you download it from the sourceforge site? It is a zip file containing the sources. Create a folder for containing the sources and unzip it. Run ant in the folder - it will create a rsyntaxtextarea.jar in the dist folder. Add this to the class path.

Comment: ya i have downloaded from the sourceforge site only,

Comment: How do i run ant in the folder?

Comment: Just type 'ant' in the folder. If ant is not installed, you may have to install it - 'sudo apt-get install ant' should do it.

Comment: Now i have compiled it, when i try to run i'm getting the error, i used `java -classpath rsyntaxtextarea.jar;. TextEditorDemo` to run.. But i'm not getting the output

Comment: Did you compile TextEditorDemo.java also? What error are you getting. The application should be opening with a small window - you can see only the title bar since you did not add any data to the text editor.

Answer (score 1):

Because that's not the path to your home directory, nor the correct slash to use.

```
javac -classpath /home/Anto/RSyntaxTextArea.jar TextEditorDemo.java
```

Also note Java 6 allows you to use a wildcard (`*`) for the path to search for jar files.

Comment: if i run like this i'm getting an another error stating that: `Class names, 'TextEditorDemo', are only accepted if annotation processing is explicitly requested`

Comment: No, that means you typed `javac -classpath /home/Anto/RSyntaxTextArea.jar TextEditorDemo` rather than what is listed above

Comment: Now i have compiled it, when i try to run i'm getting the error, i used `java -classpath rsyntaxtextarea.jar;. TextEditorDemo` to run.. But i'm not getting the output.. Could you help me with this regard?